# Why am I getting two slopes on differentiating the standard parabola equation?

Tags: calculus, slope

$y^2=4ax$

$y= \pm 2 \sqrt {ax} $

Now, we have two cases. And after differentiating both we get two different slopes which is not possible.

$\frac {dy}{dx} = \pm \frac {2a}{y}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $y^2=4ax$ defines two branches of parabola. Each branch has own slope.

Comment: $y=\pm 2\sqrt {ax}$ is not a function. They are two separate funtions. $y_1= 2\sqrt {ax}$ and $y_2=-2\sqrt {ax}$.

Comment: Add some context. What are you equations etc.. To me the "standard parabola equation" is $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and differentiating this yields $2ax+b$. Where does the square root come from in your expression?

Comment: But you also have error: $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2a}{y}$, sign $\pm$ will disappear because it appears both $y$ and $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: You say you have two cases. Show what happened when you differentiated the first case. Then what happened in the second case. If you did not do the cases one at a time like that, then that's what you did wrong.

Comment: By the way, if you just differentiate both sides of the first equation with respect to $x,$ the solution comes easily. Solving for $y$ in terms of $x$ only makes things more complicated.

Comment: For $y\geq 0$ you have $y(x)=2\cdot a^{1/2}\cdot x^{1/2}$. Differentiating w.r.t. $x$ gives $\frac{dy}{dx}=a^{1/2}\cdot x^{-1/2}=\frac{a^{1/2}}{x^{1/2}}$ Similar for $y<0$:  $y(x)=-2\cdot a^{1/2}\cdot x^{1/2}$

Comment: As others have indicated, your original analysis has no mistake.  The only mistake that you made was in interpretation, not realizing that for a specific value $x = x_0$, there were two separate points on the curve, $(x_0, y_1$ and $(x_0, y_2)$ to consider.

Comment: Alternative approach is implicit differentiation: $y^2 = 4ax \implies 2yy' = 4a.$ Since $y = \pm\sqrt{4ax}$ this translates into $\displaystyle y' = \pm \frac{4a}{2\sqrt{4ax}}.$

Comment: You could treat  x as a function of y in order to express your parabola as a function of y .  So x= f(y) =  y²/4a.  After that, you can find the derivative of x with respect to y, still as a function of y. This amounts to  rotating your graph by  90° : the Y axis becomes the independent variable axis.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful
$$y= \pm 2 \sqrt {ax}\implies \frac {dy}{dx} = \pm \frac {2a}{2 \sqrt {ax}} =\pm \frac {2a}{\pm y} = \frac {2a}{ y} $$

Your mistake was in substitution of $ 2 \sqrt {ax}$ for $y$